# SUM and Grouping by date and material

Tags: sql, sql-server

Still learning SQL forgive me.
I have 3 tables. a material table, a material_req table and a material_trans table. I want to group by material and then group columns by year.
so it would be [material, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016, total (total being the total qty used for each material.

I have tried to place the date in the select statement, and grouped by the date also. but then the returned result is a lot of the same material with a lot of dates. I only need the year. maybe try the same and return just the year?

```
SELECT  material_req.Material
    --    , Material_Trans_Date   
      , SUM(-1 * material_trans.Quantity) AS 'TOTAL'
      ,Standard_Cost

    FROM
       Material_Req inner join Material_Trans 
    ON
        Material_Req.Material_Req = Material_Trans.Material_Req
        LEFt JOIN Material
    ON
        Material.Material = Material_Req.Material
    WHERE 
      material_trans.Material_Trans_Date between '20180101' AND GETDATE() 
    --   Material_Trans_Date between '20180101' AND '20181231'
    --   Material_Trans_Date between '20170101' AND '20171231'
    --   Material_Trans_Date between '20160101' AND '20161231'
    GROUP BY 
      material_req.Material   ,Standard_Cost 

    ORDER BY 
    Material_Req.Material, Standard_Cost
```

expected results should by grouped by material, 2019, 2018, 2017,2016, Standard_Cost. the years column will have the sum of qty for each material for that year.

results look like this [current_results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HE2f4.jpg)

[image: expected results]

Comment: Please tell us what database do you use ? Thanks! Also, the results you are getting now and desired results would be nice....

Comment: That is not what I asked for. You need to write some example data. Click edit option under your question and enter some data you are getting now and what you expect to get. What would the result look like. Also, what database do you use? Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL or something else...

Comment: I have added current results. I use SQL, and I will move the results to SSRS, I will work on the expected results. and post that, above.

Comment: Add database name like oracle, sql server, etc

Comment: SQL is just language (Structured Query Language) and the database can be , as I have mentioned, Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server or something else...

Comment: Yes it its SQL Server. and I have added expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server then you might try this:

```
SELECT  material_req.Material
      , SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(YEAR, Material_Trans_Date) = '2019' THEN material_trans.Quantity ELSE 0 END) [2019 TOTAL] 
      , SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(YEAR, Material_Trans_Date) = '2018' THEN material_trans.Quantity ELSE 0 END) [2018 TOTAL]  
      ,Standard_Cost

    FROM
       Material_Req inner join Material_Trans 
    ON
        Material_Req.Material_Req = Material_Trans.Material_Req
        LEFt JOIN Material
    ON
        Material.Material = Material_Req.Material
    WHERE 
      material_trans.Material_Trans_Date between '20180101' AND GETDATE() 
    GROUP BY 
      material_req.Material   ,Standard_Cost 

    ORDER BY 
    Material_Req.Material, Standard_Cost
```

Comment: I like the answer its gets me a lot closer! thank you.

Comment: I was getting negative numbers and modified the case statement. you guys are the BEST thank you again! ```, SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(YEAR, Material_Trans_Date) = '2019' THEN -1 * material_trans.Quantity ELSE 0 END) [2019 TOTAL] 
      , SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(YEAR, Material_Trans_Date) = '2018' THEN -1 *  material_trans.Quantity ELSE 0 END) [2018 TOTAL]  ```